# There is no error in the code , but also it is not getting executed?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, if-statement

```
enrollments=[{'name':'Kinjal','account_key':4149},
            {'name':'Amruta','account_key':4162}]

unique_engagement_students={'name':'Amruta','account_key':4162}

for enrollment in enrollments:
    student = enrollment['account_key']
    if student in unique_engagement_students:
        print (enrollment)
```

Comment: It is executed, but there is no way how `student` could ever be in `unique_engagement_students`. Try to print `student`.

Comment: `student in unique_engagement_students` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: use: if student in unique_engagement_students.values():

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply compare `account_key`

```
enrollments=[{'name':'Kinjal','account_key':4149},
             {'name':'Amruta','account_key':4162}]

unique_engagement_students={'name':'Amruta','account_key':4162}

for enrollment in enrollments:
    if enrollment['account_key'] == unique_engagement_students['account_key']:
        print (enrollment)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Amruta', 'account_key': 4162}
```

Now, if `unique_engagement_students` is also `list` of `dictionary` then:

```
enrollments=[{'name':'Kinjal','account_key':4149},
             {'name':'Amruta','account_key':4162}]

unique_engagement_students=[{'name':'Amruta','account_key':4162}, 
                            {'name':'ABC','account_key':123}]

for enrollment in enrollments:
    if enrollment in unique_engagement_students:
        print (enrollment)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Amruta', 'account_key': 4162}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why it didn't work:**

it is getting executed. I added a print statement before the if statement and it did get printed.

nothing gets printed doesn't mean the program didn't get executed.In your case the expression inside of if statement never returned true so nothing gets printed. Learn how to use `print()` to debug or check in the future.

```
enrollments=[{'name':'Kinjal','account_key':4149},
            {'name':'Amruta','account_key':4162}]

unique_engagement_students={'name':'Amruta','account_key':4162}

for enrollment in enrollments:
  print("derp")
  student = enrollment['account_key']
  if student in unique_engagement_students:
      print (enrollment)
```

result:

```
derp
derp
```

**Alternative/Fix:**

```
enrollments=[{'name':'Kinjal','account_key':4149},
            {'name':'Amruta','account_key':4162}]

unique_engagement_students={'name':'Amruta','account_key':4162}

for enrollment in enrollments:
  student = enrollment['account_key']
  if student in unique_engagement_students.values():
      print (enrollment)
```

the `.values()` is getting the value inside of `unique_engagement_students` for you. Before you were comparing `student` to the `unique_engagement_students` whole dictionary

see example below:

```
print(unique_engagement_students)
print(unique_engagement_students.values())
```

result:

```
{'name': 'Amruta', 'account_key': 4162}
dict_values(['Amruta', 4162])
```

I hope this helps and welcome to StackOverflow. If you find this answer or any other answer helpful and solves your problem please mark it as the solution. That way it will help the SO community and if fellow programmers run into the same problem in the future they can find the answer easier. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
if student in unique_engagement_students:
```

by

```
if student in unique_engagement_students.values():
```

you were never entering this `if statement` simply because you were comparing the dictionary's `keys` with an integer expected to be in the `values` of the dictionary.
Hope this helped.

Comment: This helped , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
enrollments=[{'name':'Kinjal','account_key':4149},
            {'name':'Amruta','account_key':4162}]

unique_engagement_students=[4162]

for enrollment in enrollments:
    student = enrollment['account_key']
    if student in unique_engagement_students:
        print (enrollment)
```

I'll update to add an explanation.

Comment: Changing the data of  `unique_engagement_students` isn't a good solution. We should assume this is a MRE and that the unique_ dataset could be much larger. Instead of changing the example data, changing the `if` statement to `if student in unique_engagement_students.values():` would produce the desired output.